# Cannot convert method group 'SingleOrDefault' to non-delegate type 'Product'. Did you intend to invoke the method?

Tags: c#, .net, linq, methods

Here's my code. I keep getting this error. I'm pretty new to programming and this website. Hope I posted the questions properly. Thanks

```
protected void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    using(TestEntities myEntity = new TestEntities())
    {
        Product myProduct;

        //if insert
        if (_id == -1)
        {
            myProduct = new Product();
            myProduct.CreateDateTime = DateTime.Now;
            myProduct.UpdateDateTime = DateTime.Now;
            myEntity.AddToProducts(myProduct); 

        }

            //update case
        else
        {
            myProduct = (from p in myEntity.Products
                         where p.ProductID == _id
                         **select p).SingleOrDefault;**
            myProduct.UpdateDateTime = DateTime.Now;
        }
```

Comment: "Did you intend to invoke the method?"  You did()

Answer (score 2):

From the error and without looking at your code you are missing methods `()` with `SingleOrDefault`. It should be like:

```
var product = query.SingleOrDefault();
                                 //^^^^ Missing brackets
```

Since you posted your code it is clear that you are **missing brackets** with `SingleOrDefault`

```
myProduct = (from p in myEntity.Products
             where p.ProductID == _id
             select p).SingleOrDefault();
                                   //^^^^ here
```

Since `SingleOrDefault` accepts a predicate you can do:

```
myProduct = myEntity.Products.SingleOrDefault(r=> r.ProductID == _id);
```

Comment: Oh, silly mistake. I added the brackets, but I'm still getting the same error message

Comment: @user3037945, are you sure ? just clean/rebuild, is the error on some different line now ?

Comment: my new error message is:  Cannot implicitly convert type 'TestModel.Product' to 'Product'

Comment: @user3037945, now that is a separate error and it appears that you have two `Product` classes in your project. There should be one.

Comment: Hmmm okay. I'll see if I can find where I did that. Thank you